# Slow down associated with vector::push_back and placement new in a multithreaded application

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a multithreaded application in which my thread utilization is very poor (in the ball park of 1%-4% per thread, with fewer threads than processors).  In the debugger, it appears to be spending a lot of time in vector::push_back, specifically the placement new that occurs during the push_back.  I've tried using reserve to avoid having the vector expand its capacity and copy everything, but that doesn't appear to be the problem.  Commenting out the vector::push_backs leads to much better thread utilization.

This problem is occurring with vectors of uint64_t, so it does not appear to be the result of complicated object construction.  I have tried using both the standard allocator and a custom allocator and both perform the same way. The vectors are being used by the same thread that allocated them.

Comment: You should add the concrete platform/compiler that you are using, as these type of performance related questions might be bound to some specific implementation rather than the language itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need these initialized to 0, consider writing a vector-like class which *does not* initialize. I've found this to provide measurable performance gains in some scenarios.

Side note: When your profiler claims you're spending most your time with primitive operations on 64-bit integers, you know the rest of your code is optimized decently.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something trivial that won't really work, but as the `push_back` calls create an new item, why not initialize the vector to all 0's, and access the elements with something like `at` or `operator[]`. That should get rid of any lock on the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Does the thread utilization improve if you only use one thread? If so, perhaps you are running afoul of some sort of heap lock, eg

[In multithreaded C/C++, does malloc/new lock the heap when allocating memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524437/in-multithreaded-c-c-does-malloc-new-lock-the-heap-when-allocating-memory)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx