# How does Mono handle forking in Process.Start under unix-y systems?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, mono, posix

Under Unix-y systems (by unix-y I mean those that implement POSIX fork & exec, but no other process creation mechanism), processes are created by forking and exec-ing the target executable. However, it is [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235516/fork-in-multi-threaded-program) that forking threaded applications is a bad idea. Since all Mono applications are multithreaded by the virtue of the GC running in its own thread(s), how does Mono handle Process.Start()?

I've [dug a bit in the codebase](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/8aeab70720ffa7c0feb5e380391bb55b4874d013/mono/metadata/w32process-unix.c#L1845), but all I could find is a regular fork & exec. What's happening to the locks? Does the runtime do some thread magic?

Comment: The caveat about blending threads and processes concerns ongoing activity in each; for example you have 3 threads, fork, and expect the 3 threads in the child to function seemlessly.   The magic to make that happen is pthread_atfork(3), but magic needs to be summoned, and often it isn't.  A simple fork() from a multi-threaded program that does not interact with the thread environment can be expected to work -- so fork() + exec() is typically ok.  Mono (or other frameworks) may be able to interfere with this, but I can't imagine why it would.

Comment: Between fork and exec, one needs to call various helper functions for things like redirecting stdio or doing tracing. But even memory allocation requires locks (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524437/in-multithreaded-c-c-does-malloc-new-lock-the-heap-when-allocating-memory).

Comment: For example, the code call mono_trace in the child, which, under tracing (https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/3c8a5e775073f93cabeac0990a264ce1995eb396/mono/utils/mono-logger-internals.h) calls mono_tracev_inner (https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/3c8a5e775073f93cabeac0990a264ce1995eb396/mono/utils/mono-logger.c), which calls g_vasprintf, which allocates memory: https://people.gnome.org/~ryanl/glib-docs/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-vasprintf